# Rotating div AND text in opposite directions whilst keeping them aligned?

Tags: css, button, rotation, hover, font-awesome

So I'm making this button whick I would like to animate when hovered over. So far it works great but the font awesome icon I'm using seems to knock itself out of alignment when it rotates.

Basically I've rotated the parent div 45 degrees on hover.

To counteract this I've also rotated the font awesome icon -45 degrees on hover.

However for some reason this caused it to move to the left. How do I position this so it doesn't move (or at least, doesn't give the impression that it moves) when hovered upon.

Check out the jsfiddle here :
https://jsfiddle.net/krustytoast/eu4dugdz/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="scroll"><i class="fa fa-angle-down scrollicon"></i></div>
#scroll {
width:70px;
height: 70px;
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
font-size: 75px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 64px;
border-radius: 50%;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
border-color: #FFFFFF;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;}


.scrollicon {
line-height: 64px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}


#scroll:hover .scrollicon,
#scroll:hover ~ .scrollicon {

line-height: 74px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


#scroll:hover {
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 0%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

The movement on my site is far more pronounced than this btw.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've fixed it (kind-of) with trial and error padding, to the point it looks ok. Still wondering if there is a cleaner/ more effective way of doing this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep height and width of the inner `i` at **100%** the parent size!
in order to manipulate with it's size set it to `inline-block`

My take:

```css
body{background:#678;}

#scroll {
  width:      70px;
  height:     70px;
  cursor:     pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border:     5px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#scroll > i {
  display:     inline-block;
  width:       100%;
  height:      100%;
  line-height: 74px;
  font-size:   74px;
  text-align:  center;
  color:       white;
  transition:  0.5s;
}

#scroll:hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  transform:     rotate(45deg);
}
#scroll:hover > i {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div id="scroll">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! That looks like it. I'll try it once I get home and I'll let you know, cheers mate.